# adding click listener on circle is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add click listener on  my map and here is my code for this

**update**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<style>
    #map-canvas{
 width:500px; 
 height:500px;
}
</style>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var cityPoints = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
        id: 0,
        addr: 'avenue0',
        magnitude: 100000
    };

    var cityCircle;
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<div>Hello! World</div>",
        maxWidth: 500
    });


  function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 4,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.2330555556, 72.3330555556),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
 };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      clickable: true,
      fillOpacity: 0,
      map: map,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.231867, 72.33336),
      radius: 200000
  };

  cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);


    google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function (ev) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(ev.latLng);
        infoWindow.open(map);
    });
}
initialize();
</script>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this code is not working for me becasue infor window is not opening when i click on circle.Plz any one tell what exactly i am missing in my code.Plz Help

Comment: `infowindow != infoWindow`

Comment: I have done this but still not working

Comment: i mean this `infoWindow.setPosition(ev.latLng);
        infoWindow.open(map);`

Comment: What is your console saying? Is there an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` is what is missing.
And here is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/9bnCw/6/

I made the radius a little bigger.

**UPDATE**

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bujar/9bnCw/7/) work?

**UPDATE 3**

I've put it all in one file so you can copy and paste it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <style>
 #map-canvas{ 
 height:100%;
 width:100%;           
}
 html, body {
     height: 100%;
 }    
 body {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
 }           
        </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
        <script>
            var cityPoints = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
  id: 0,
  addr: 'avenue0',
  magnitude: 100000
};

var cityCircle;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<div>Hello! World</div>",
        maxWidth: 500
    });

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.231867, 72.33336),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

           var populationOptions = {
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        clickable: true,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        map: map,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.231867, 72.33336),
        radius: 200000
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function(ev) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(ev.latLng);
            infoWindow.open(map);
        });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>  
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What update? I don't see anything in the comments or the question

Comment: Ohhh you mean you added the initialize() in the end of your code. If my code helped you, you should mark it as answered, if not you should at least mark your title as closed

Comment: @user2024024: your "update" didn't reflect this answer. The call of initialize comes too early in yor "update", because the #map-canvas is still unknown at the time you call initialize(it works in the fiddle, because the code there will be executed onload). However, the call of `initialize()` can't be the issue here, because in your original question you said that the map has been loaded(it wouldn't when the call of initialize failed). By that, this answer did not solve the issue (but the fiddle does, because it fixes the misspelled *infoWindow* , as noted in my comment)

Comment: Sir I meant the code in My Update according to you is not working for me

Comment: This Code Just Working In fiddle Not on web Page

Comment: Check the update. If that doesn't work either then you'll have to be more specific

Comment: No Sir Still Not Working U can Check here is live Link http://202.125.144.34/map/el.aspx

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
Ypu are getting this error. This has nothing to do with the map. Debug your program first.

Comment: Check my latest update. Just copy and paste the code as you see it.

Comment: yes its working now will u plz tell me what was the issue exactly

Comment: Who said it can't? Check the code I've updated it. And if this answers your question mark the answer as accepted.